# Data cannot be saved to database the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this code, it works perfectly for me, the problem is that it does not save me in the database the first time, I must reload the page and then try again to make it work.
I can't find the error
then I am going to leave you the code of my controller so that you can give me a hand of what may be happening

```
class EvolutionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :load_patient
  before_action :set_evolution, only: :show 
  before_action :verify_permission, only: %i[new show create edit update destroy]

  def index
    @evolutions = @patient.evolutions # You could skip this and just use @patient.evolutions in your view if you like
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build
  end

  def create
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.build(evolution_params)

    if @evolution.save
      redirect_to patients_url, notice: 'La evolucion fue agregada con exito'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
  end

  def destroy
  @evolution = @patient.evolutions.find(params[:id])
  @evolution.destroy
  redirect_to patient_path(@patient)
  flash[:notice] = "Evolución eliminada"
  end

  private
  def load_patient
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
  end
    
  def set_evolution
    @evolution = @patient.evolutions.find(params[:id])
  end

  def verify_permission
    redirect_to patients_path if !user_signed_in? || @patient.user != current_user
  end

  def evolution_params
    params.require(:evolution).permit(:motivo, :entrevista, :patient_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: you could use `@evolution.save!` and see the output error on console log

Comment: Thanks for answering, but the console does not throw any error, so I do not know what it could be

Comment: so it redirect to the patients page and there's no the newest patient in list ?

Comment: Yes, the patient is in the list, the problem is that the submit button in evolution does not perform any action, but after reloading the page and trying again if it works perfectly